# Flutter with continous location listen in background android

Tags: android, flutter

Since the release of Flutter, I'm really curious about it's UI. I have existing android code with MVP + Volley network. Currently, the android location update works even in doze mode and updates it's location correctly in the background.

Is there any way like geocoder of flutter?. It can listen to the fusedlocationapi but not sure about background listening. Please suggest a better way in flutter or should I use the android way to update its location and save it.

Thanks